# MySQL data backup?

Tags: mysql

I have an database with tons of data in it.
I also wrote a new program that will change the data in the database.
Is there any way to make a copy of the database before i run my program?
Or is there any other solution?

What I'm thiking is making a copy of the database,
Run the program, which modified the main database. If things goes wrong, how do I use my copied database data to revert the main database?

Please provide steps and commands on linux. I'm new with the database mysql and its commands.

Comment: Offtopic. not a programming question. This is more DBA-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the following link this will tell you how to dump your database via different ways and restore it.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Basic command to dump a single database is:
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mysqldump` command to make a backup of your database and overwrite the backup file everytime

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p <db> > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make a copy of the database before i run my program?

Yes, there's. You have to use the client utility [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) before run you app.

It is something like

```
shell> mysqldump [options] > dump.sql
```